# error while running flask api : __getattr__ raise AttributeError("module {!r} has no attribute "

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My flask api was running , I cloned it in a new repository in order to push it to github (because in the first repository some deleted dataset still appear while i commit and push and then it won't work because of the size), this program used to run easily, and now it shows this error, I am stuck for 3days on this, can anyone help please, I couldn't debug this error even though I am not using numpy explicitly, it shows this numpy related error.

```
> File "/Users/sa/api-flask2/flask_app.py", line 5, in <module>
>     import pandas as pd   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py",
> line 180, in <module>
>     import pandas.testing   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/testing.py",
> line 5, in <module>
>     from pandas._testing import (   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_testing.py",
> line 24, in <module>
>     import pandas._libs.testing as _testing   File "pandas/_libs/testing.pyx", line 10, in init pandas._libs.testing  
> File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py",
> line 284, in __getattr__
>     raise AttributeError("module {!r} has no attribute " AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'bool'
> 
> Process finished with exit code 1
```

[image]

Comment: Copy the code and the error. Please no screenshots: they are difficult to read and we are lazy: we will just skip the question instead of transcribing the text in the answer. For you it is easy: you can just copy past (and few formatting) the text.

Comment: I just added the code just in case, but actually, you should  click on the image and you can see that it's very easy to read

Comment: But we cannot copy the errors in the answer. And it makes your question difficult to be in Google. This is a reference site, not a forum: we want that the questions and answers will be useful for many people.

Comment: Did you upgraded pandas or the active environment recently?

Comment: well I think not, I haven't upgrade pandas

Comment: Also not other components? Sometime such crazy errors are due to dirt environment (some leftover of previous versions, usually the compiled files. If nothing work, try to export your environment (the list of package to install) and do a new one).

Comment: You only copied the error messages as text, but not the code, and the code in the screenshot is not the one that produced the error message, as the line numbers don't match.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you highlighted is the callback, the error is AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'bool'.

Based on [the GitHub issue](https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT/issues/2567) it seems to be an issue with Numpy 1.24, try downgrading to 1.23.

Comment: my numpy version is actually 1.23.5

Comment: I have replicated this with NumPy 1.23.5 and am pointed towards [here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations). You mention not using NumPy explicitly so just through Pandas I assume, what version of Pandas are you using?

Comment: my pandas version is 1.5.2

Comment: I thought as well that pandas was the problem , since the first line of the error refers to the import pandas , I really don't get this error